Meta Query conditional nest arrays
I have a page which displays a product list with 3 filters to sort them. Brand, pet type and category. Two of them work but I can't seem to get the third to filter with the rest.
I'm trying a nested meta query but it's not working either so I was wondering if anbody could double check my formatting to see if i've made a mistake.
// Get products by categories
$contents = [];
foreach($categories as $category){
    $obj = new StdClass;
    $obj->category = $category;

    // Get posts
    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
                    'field' => 'term_id', 
                    'terms' => $category->term_id,
                    'include_children' => false
                )
            )
    );

    if($brand_filter and $pet_filter) {

        $args = new WP_Query( 
                array(
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'key' => 'product_related_pet', // name of custom field
                            'value' => '"'.$pet_filter.'"', // matches exactly the id   
                            'compare' => 'LIKE'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => 'product_related_brand', // name of custom field
                            'value' => '"'.$brand_filter.'"', // matches exactly the id
                            'compare' => 'LIKE'
                        ),
                    )
                ) 
        );

    } else if ($pet_filter){
        $args['meta_query'] = [
            [
                'key' => 'product_related_pet', // name of custom field
                'value' => '"'.$pet_filter.'"', // matches exactly the id
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
              ]
        ];

    } else if ($brand_filter){
        $args['meta_query'] = [
            [
                'key' => 'product_related_brand', // name of custom field
                'value' => '"'.$brand_filter.'"', // matches exactly the id
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
              ]
        ];
    }
    
    
    $products = Timber::get_posts($args);
    $obj->products = $products;

    $contents[] = $obj;
}


Please Never post images of or off site links to Code/Data/Error Messages.
Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. This is so that we can try to reproduce the
problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

I doubt that $args = new WP_Query(...) makes much sense.
